# ¿Cuando usar en CSS border:0 y cuando border:none?

Tags: css, css3

Intentando ayudar a un compañero con otra pregunta de stackoverflow me ha surgido esta duda. ¿Cuando es mejor usar 'border: none' y cuando 'border:0'? ¿Hay alguna diferencia de funcionamiento, cual?¿En que supuesto una es más eficaz que otra?

```
 .miccs{border:0}
```

o

```
 .micss{border:none}
```

Comment: `border: none` se usa principalmente para eliminar los bordes por defecto que le dan los navegadores a los inputs y buttons.

`border: 0` se puede usar para dar animaciones a elementos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La diferencia es solo el valor de la propiedad que estas empleando, al final estas haciendo lo mismo, ocultal el border y hacer que este no ocupe espacio en el bloque o caja:

Cuando especificas border 0 haces referencia al sufijo width:

```
border: 0; = border-width: 0;
```

cuando especificas border none haces referencia al sufijo style:

```
border: none = border-style: none;
```

En conclusión ambos funcionan de la misma manera.

Answer (score 0):

El borde tiene cuatro lados y tres atributos por lado:
  - el ancho
   - tipo de línea
    - color.

Podemos establecer el mismo atributo a todos los lados:

```
    border: 1px solid red;
```

Podemos ocultar los bordes sin perder los otros atributos:

```
        border:0
```

se conserva solid y red por si más adelante tenemos que hacer aparer las líneas.

o podemos deshacernos de todis por ejemplos bordes que vienen establecidos en los temas:

```
      border:none
```

existen otras combinaciones pero son las más usadas

Comment: Ojo luego de border:none tendríamos que volver a definir estilo y color.

Answer (score -1):

La unica diferencia que hay entre los dos son los valores, en uno se pone el valor a `0` y en otro a `none`, como resultado final obstendrás el mismo resultado:

Quitar los bordes:

```css
border: none
```

Y esta otra opción deja todos los bordes a 0:

```css
border: 0
```

Las dos opciones son iguales pero con diferentes valores.

Comment: Trata de ampliar un poco tu respuesta para que sea bien recibida, tal como está es considerada de baja calidad, por esa razón tienes votos negativos. Te invito a hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas de lo que hablo.